# Can a province be considered neighbor if divided by a sea?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

**Can a province be considered neighbor if divided by a sea ?** If yes, what's the distance limit to create a claim on it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is considered neighboring, if you share a sea zone.

E.g. southern england and northern france is divided by the channel, each province there is considered neighboring for purposes of creating claims. But once you have to traverse more than one sea zone it is no longer considered neighboring.

Comment: Does 'sharing a sea zone' mean they have to have their port in the same sea zone? Or do the provinces just need to have a coast with a common sea zone?